# How to display clickable hyperlink in Papplet Java application?

Tags: java, hyperlink, applet, processing, clickable

I know how to display simple text with the processing.core.PApplet.text method.
But this one can't display clickable hypertext link. How could I make that in Papplet ?

I precise that link should open the web browser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented on the main Reference page at http://processing.org/reference/, but you can use a function called 'link()' ... it takes up to two parameters - the url to go to, and if the second argument is supplied, sets whether to open a new page or not...

Eg.

link("http://www.processing.org", "_new");